# Total Sum and Partial Sum

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently using SSMS. I am pulling data, and trying to get two different columns that sum prices. The two columns 'ChangeSpend' and 'TotalSpend' both reference the same column and this is where I am running into problems.

I want ChangeSpend to return the sum of all the codes per receipt that start with V.Ch% (so they exclude all the others) and the TotalSpend to sum all of the codes for each receipt.

Here is my current code:

```
SELECT 
      Receipt
      ,ReceiptCode
      ,ReceiptAmount
      ,sum(ReceiptAmount) over (Partition by Receipt) as TotalSpend
      ,(CASE WHEN ReceiptCode = 'V.Ch%' then sum(ReceiptAmount) 
                                             over (Partition by Receipt) 
      ELSE 0
      END) as ChangeSpend
  FROM tableA
  LEFT OUTER JOIN tableB
  on A.Receipt = B.Receipt
  WHERE ReceiptCode LIKE 'V.%'
  ORDER BY Receipt
```

However, my query currently prints this:

```
Receipt    ReceiptCode    ReceiptAmount    TotalSpend    ChangeSpend
1          v.cha          5                20            0         
1          v.rt           2                20            0
1          v.chb          6                20            0
1          v.abc          7                20            0
2          v.cha          20               21            0
2          v.abc          1                21            0
3          v.cha          4                14            0
3          v.chb          1                14            0
3          v.tye          7                14            0
3          v.chs          2                14            0
```

And I would like it to print this:

```
Receipt    ReceiptCode    ReceiptAmount    TotalSpend    ChangeSpend
1          v.cha          5                20            11         
1          v.rt           2                20            11
1          v.chb          6                20            11
1          v.abc          7                20            11
2          v.cha          20               21            20
2          v.abc          1                21            20
3          v.cha          4                14            7
3          v.chb          1                14            7
3          v.tye          7                14            7
3          v.chs          2                14            7
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: `CASE WHEN ReceiptCode like 'V.Ch%`  <-- Using LIKE operator may help.

Comment: Also, it makes sense to write a subquery for this

Comment: When I do that, it changes the problem of having 0 appear next to the Receipts, but it does not sum them (it would just print 5 and 6 in the corresponding line for Receipt 1)

Comment: could you provide a test schema?  Problem is that you want us to provide you an answer based on the Finish Line.  In order to validate your query first and assist in providing the answer, we need context

Comment: Sorry, I read the data wrong, when I change that it just prints the Total instead of strictly the V.Ch prices. And what is a test schema?

Comment: change this `CASE WHEN ReceiptCode = 'V.Ch%' then` to `CASE WHEN ReceiptCode like 'V.Ch%' then` and let us know the result

Comment: Test schema is the root Table structure, with some Test data, so we can model your environment.

Comment: @GoldBishop I changed it to LIKE instead of = and it now print the TotalSpend on each line containing v.ch%

Also, I cannot post the table it is pulling from because it is a database...

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @nola94 we need the Table & Data schema to provide the answer you request.  We need to know where the data is coming from and a test sample of data to fill it with.  We do not need your organizational data, just representative data that should assist with the solving your problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
,SUM(CASE WHEN ReceiptCode LIKE 'V.Ch%' THEN ReceiptAmount ELSE 0 END) 
 OVER (Partition by Receipt) 
   AS ChangeSpend
```

Comment: YES THIS WORKED!!

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the SUM outside the CASE, not the other way around:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN SomeCondition=true THEN MyColumn ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but when I try to write

`sum(CASE WHEN ReceiptCode = 'V.Ch%' then (ReceiptAmount) over (Partition by Receipt) 
      ELSE 0
      END) as ChangeSpend`

I get an error regarding the word 'over'?

Comment: Put the `OVER...` outside of the `SUM()`.   After the `END)`

Answer (score 1):

This may help:

```
    Create Table Payment(
    Receipt Int,
    ReceiptCode VARCHAR(10),
    ReceiptAmount decimal)


    Insert Into Payment
    Values
    (1, 'v.cha', 5),
    (1, 'v.rt', 2),
    (1, 'v.chb', 6),
    (1, 'v.abc', 7),
    (2, 'v.cha', 20),
    (2, 'v.abc', 1),
    (3, 'v.cha', 4),
    (3, 'v.chb', 1),
    (3, 'v.the', 7),
    (3, 'v.chs', 2);

    SELECT  * ,
        SUM(ReceiptAmount) OVER ( PARTITION BY Receipt ) AS TotalSpend ,
        SUM(IIF(ReceiptCode LIKE 'v.ch%',ReceiptAmount,0)) OVER ( PARTITION 
        BY Receipt ) AS ChangeSpend
    FROM    payment;
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
    SUM(
CASE WHEN ReceiptCode like 'V.Ch%' then ReceiptAmount ELSE 0 END) as ChangeSpend
```